# Deleted answers and Enlightened badge

Tags: support, badges, deleted-answers, enlightened-badge

Suppose that these events occur by this order:

- Someone posts a question.
- User A posts an answer.
- User B posts an answer.
- The answer posted by user A gets deleted.
- The answer posted by user B gets accepted; also it gets a score of 10.

In this situation, will user B get the Enlightened badge? The [badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) in the Help Center says that that badge is given under these conditions:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more.

But it is not clear (at least not to me) whether or not an answer is considered as the first answer if it is just the first *undeleted* answer.

Comment: TL;DR for those who prefer not to read the dupe: the badge is indeed given to the first undeleted answer that is accepted and having score of 10. (or more)